# Find a finite automaton such that the language accepted by it is the set of even numbers in binary notation

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Use automata theory to prove the following question

Comment: How is the input provided? What order are the bits in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L = \{(0+1)^*0\}$. This langage is precisely the set of even integers written in binary notation.

Now just make the following two states NFA  :

> - $q_0$ is the first state
> - $q_1$ is the second states and it's a final state
> - $q_0 \overset{\Sigma}{\longrightarrow} q_0$
> - $q_0 \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} q_1$

You can also make a three states DFA that solves the problem :

> - $q_0$ is the first state
> - $q_1$ is the second states and it's final state
> - $q_2$ is the third states
> - $q_0 \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} q_1$
> - $q_0 \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} q_2$
> - $q_1 \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} q_1$
> - $q_1 \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} q_2$
> - $q_2 \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} q_1$
> - $q_2 \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} q_2$

Comment: I have a doubt in q1, why 0,1?

Comment: Why is 0 not accepted?

Comment: @copper.hat ? it's accepeted

Comment: @UnknownX because we need to recognise the $(0+1)^*$ part. If you prefer you can write it like : $q_1 \overset{\Sigma}{\longrightarrow} q_1$

Comment: Are you presuming the input is LSB first?

Comment: @copper.hat you are right I am going to edit

Comment: So, the finite automaton answer are the two states, q0 and q1? why is not posible more states?

Comment: @UnknownX you can add more states if you want. Here it's an NFA but you can apply any algorithms of your choice to transform it into an DFA.